# Zxing android library qr code scan change to landscape mode

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am working on qrcode scanner app, its working fine in phone but when i test this app in tablet , scan qr code return in landscape mode and i have change my xml and java file with portrait mode.

here is my code:

```
 qrScan_visitor = new IntentIntegrator(this);
 qrScan_visitor.setCameraId(1);
 qrScan.setOrientationLocked(false);
 qrScan.initiateScan();
```

where xml code:

```
   <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:name=".MobileVerify"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work, this is my activity change in landscape like this [image: strong text]?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to put more code and explain the exact part where you face the problem. The code added by you is not self-explanatory

Comment: tools:replace="screenOrientation" try removing this code

Comment: After removing this tools:replace="screenOrientation" again its change to landscape and after a second change to portrait.

Comment: using another app and check QR code is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in android phone, after adding this in AndroidManifest file my problem resolved

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33608040)